# Predict issue with sciklearn ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the decision boundaries for several classifiers. But I was not able to run:

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

without an error message.

Please help me discover what I am doing wrong ?

Here is my code:

```
pas = 0.02    
x_min, x_max = iris.data[:,0].min()-1, iris.data[:,0].max()+1
y_min, y_max = iris.data[:,1].min()-1, iris.data[:,1].max()+1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(x_min, x_max, pas),
    np.arange(y_min, y_max, pas))

for clf, subfig in zip(classifieurs, subfigs.reshape(-1)):
    # TODO Q2B
    # EntraÃ®nez le classifieur
    clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

    # TODO Q2B
    # Obtenez et affichez son erreur (1 - accuracy)
    # Stockez la valeur de cette erreur dans la variable err
    err = 1 - accuracy_score(clf.predict(iris.data), iris.target)
    print("Taux d'erreur pour", clf.__class__.__name__, "est de:", err*100, "%")

    # TODO Q2B
    # Utilisez la grille que vous avez crÃ©Ã©e plus haut
    # pour afficher les rÃ©gions de dÃ©cision, de mÃªme
    # que les points colorÃ©s selon leur vraie classe
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]);
    Z = Z.reshape(x.shape)
    subfig.contourf(x, y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)

    # Identification des axes et des mÃ©thodes
    subfig.set_xlabel(data.feature_names[f1])
    subfig.set_ylabel(data.feature_names[f2])
    subfig.set_title(clf.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: I am having a problem with:  Z=clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

Comment: Can we see full error message? Also please report the shapes of `xx` and `yy`. Probably shapes of these variables are not compatible.

Comment: The full error message: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (61600,2) (4,)

Comment: xx: (220, 280) yy: (220, 280)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to plot the decision surface, right ?

---

You get this error because you first fit the classifier `clf` using:

```
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Now, `iris.data` contains 4 features/variables:

```
print(iris.data.shape)
(150, 4)
```

Next, you are trying to predict using data that contain only 2 varaibles/features:

```
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

print(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()].shape)
(61600, 2)
```

---

### How to solve this

To solve this use 2 features initially.

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
Y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data.
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, edgecolors='k')
plt.title('3-Class classification using Support Vector Machine')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]